# C++: How do I make a copy of a char returned as reference?

Tags: c++, char, reference, return-by-reference

If I do

```
string someString = "hello";
char c = someString[2];
```

does the `c` variable refer to a character inside `someString`, or is it a new independent char on it's own?

If it is not independent, how do I copy it?

Comment: It is already a copy of that value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`c` is a copy. If you wrote

```
char &c = someString[2];
```

then it would have been a reference.

Answer (score 5):

```
char c = someString[2];
```

copies the character at position 2 into 'c'

Answer (score 3):

It's independent because `c` is not a reference type - it is `char`, not `char &`.

A consequent of it being a value type, a copy is thus performed.